# Анимация в JQuery

Tags: jquery

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать рекламную анимацию в jquery.
Есть кусок скрипта, выводящий одну картинку:

```
$('#some ul li img').hide();
function animation () {
    $('#some ul li img').fadeIn(5000);
    $('#some ul li img').fadeOut(5000);
}
setInterval(animation,1000);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="some">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/foto1.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Здесь нужно выводить все картинки в списке по очереди, то есть выходит первая в списке,  исчезает, потом вторая и т.д.

Comment: а в чём именно затруднения? код, вроде именно это и подразумевает. PS вы бы начали с правил разметки на форуме

Comment: этот код выводит корректно только одну картинку а если поставить несколько они выводятся одновременно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Менять путь к новому изображению, можно используя метод [.attr()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8):

```
$('#some ul li img').attr("src","images/foto2.jpg");
```

[[@orik80](/users/2584/orik80)](/users/2584/orik80) **UPD:**
Нет времени раскладывать всё по полочкам, посему даю намек:
http://jsfiddle.net/NHnQS/ Доработаете чуток сами.

Comment: На самом деле менять путь к новому изображению можно и без attr, достаточно:

     this.src = 'img/imgName';

Проблемы при таком подходе возможны (и то, маловероятны) в IE<7v.

Comment: с изменением атрибута показывает только последний

Comment: ого!!!! не думал что delay скопировали из delphi в jquery круто и самое главное работает!!!!

Answer (score 1):

для перебора всех фотографий в списке используйте метод `.each()`. например,

```
function animation () {
$('#some ul li img').each(function() {
   $(this).fadeIn(5000);
   $(this).fadeOut(5000);
}
```

Comment: это не работает они появляются и исчезают одновременно

Comment: Ладно попытаюсь сам разобраться всем спасибо

Comment: тут нужен цикл for и setTimeout, причем надо посчитать время анимации картинки, т.е.

     var startD = new Date().getTime();
     var animationTime;
     // тут анимация, на callback вешаем че-то типа
     animationTime = new Date().getTime()-startD;

     // ну и потом по стальным элементам в цикле for, просто
     for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {
          setTimeout(function(){
              // тут анимация
          }, (i+1)*animationTime)
     }

Так что задача не такая простая как может показаться тем кто не реализовывал подобного