# Анимация с помощью fadeIn и fadeOut

Tags: jquery

Кто может подсказать, как сделать анимацию с помощью `fadeIn` и `fadeOut`?
То есть нужно выводить и скрывать по очереди несколько изображений в цикле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я дополнил ответ по [предыдущему вашему вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/67170/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-jquery), связанному с этим. Дублировать тут уже не буду.

Answer (score 0):

Для обхода группы изображений используется `.each()`. Ну а в использовании `.fadeIn()` и  `fadeOut()` тоже затруднений не возникает. Просто надо немного почитать и понять.